# Set Text Con PytQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Estoy intentado imprimir en un Text Browser resultados de unas sumas dentro de un ciclo FOR

```
    def calcularDistanciaM(self):

    NumCal=self.dialogo.txt_Nombre.text()
    fila= int(NumCal)

    cont = 0
    x = np.random.randint(0, 10, (5))
    y = np.random.randint(0, 10, (100, 5))
    for i in range(fila):
        for j in range(5):
            cont = np.absolute(x[j] - y[i, j])
        self.dialogo.mostrar.setText((str(i) + ": " + str(cont)) + '\n')

        cont = 0
```

Pero solo me imprime la ultima suma

Answer (score 0):

El método `setText()` tiene como objetivo reemplazar todo el texto pero ese no es el objetivo del AP. En vez de ello se debe usar el método `append()` que añade el texto al final.